# Изменить скорость движения мяча с клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, canvas, keydown

Я создал обработчик нажатий клавиш, который передаёт инфу о нажатии keydown 
в переменную speed со значением в соответствии нажатия клавиш. Значения определяются объектом speeds. Дальше  создал в конструкторе Ball
новое свойство speed, хранящее скорость мяча, и использовал
его в методе setDirection, через аргумент. Добавил аргументу значение по умолчанию так как мяч пропадал. Судя по всему он не передаёт скорость в метод setDirection. Надо чтобы скорость менялась в зависимости от нажатия клавиш

```js
let canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
  width = canv.width,
  height = canv.height;
let circle = (x, y, radius, fillCircle) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
let Ball = function() {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 5;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.speed = 5; // свойство скорости, которое должно изменяться в
  //зависимости от нажатия, установил начальную, но она не меняется.
};
Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
  if (this.x < 10) {
    this.xSpeed = 5
  } else if (this.x > width - 10) {
    this.xSpeed = -5
  } else if (this.y < 10) {
    this.ySpeed = 5
  } else if (this.y > height - 10) {
    this.ySpeed = -5
  }
};
Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true);
};
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function(direction, speed = 5) {
  if (direction === "down") {
    this.ySpeed = speed;
    this.xSpeed = 0
  } else if (direction === "up") {
    this.ySpeed = -speed;
    this.xSpeed = 0
  } else if (direction === "right") {
    this.xSpeed = speed;
    this.ySpeed = 0
  } else if (direction === "left") {
    this.xSpeed = -speed;
    this.ySpeed = 0
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
    this.ySpeed = 0;
    this.xSpeed = 0
  }
};
let ball = new Ball;
let keyAction = {
  32: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down",
};
$('body').keydown((event) => {
  var direction = keyAction[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});
let speeds = {
  49: 1,
  50: 2,
  51: 3,
  52: 4,
  53: 5,
  54: 6,
  55: 7,
  56: 8,
  57: 9
};
$('body').keydown((event) => { // а это сам обработчик 
  var speed = speeds[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(null, speed);
});


setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.move();
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canv" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос сводится к другому вопросу, который будет звучать иначе - как сделать на js ввод с клавиатуры, например. Или как обрабатывать нажатие стрелочек в js...

Comment: @nick_n_a  Согласен, но изменить направление получается стрелками, а скорость нет. По-этому я хотел уточнить, что именно из ввода не получается

Comment: Как именно вы хотите менять скорость? Уваличить в разы? Увеличить на 1? Уменьшить? Задать конкретную?

Comment: @nick_n_a  команду должны задавать нажатые клавиши. Они все записаны в объекте speeds. ключ - клавиша, значение - скорость. И эта скорость должна передаваться в качестве аргумента в setDirections (в анонимную функцию).

Comment: @nick_n_a В названии написано) если надо продублировать в описании, то я могу. не хотел повторяться.

Comment: У вас в `setDirections` не прописано действие для цифр.

Comment: Я бы делал один обработчик клавиатуры. Два обработчика сбивают с толку.

Comment: @nick_n_a  только что попробовал объеденить, ещё больше ошибок полезло( хочу задать скорость нажатием клавиши. 1 - смещение на один пиксель 2 - на 2px и т.д.

Comment: У вас во первых, в setDirections не прописано действие для цифр, во воторых, вы неправильно делаете вызов setDirection, думая что имя аргумента пробросится во второй аргумент. 1. Добавить ветку в setDirections, 2. Переделать строку `ball.setDirection(speed);`  так что б speed была вторым аргументом.

Comment: @nick_n_a 1. цифры сами по себе никаких действий не производят, они лишь меняют скорость. Смысл писать if(speed === 1) { speed = 1} else if и т.д.  2. ball.setDirection(null, speed);
Итог: всё по старому

Comment: *никаких действий не производят* не равно *они лишь меняют скорость*. Меняют скорость, значит в setDirection должно быть прописано как именно меняют скорость. 2. конечно все по старому, но с оговоркой, теперь direction=null а speed = столько сколько надо, а уже то что вы в setDirection не предусмотрели смену скорости - то уже добавьте ветку в if которая меняет скорость, сама она - не поменяется. Двойная ошибка - означает что в двух местах надо код поправить. В одном, будем считать - исправлено.

Comment: @nick_n_a чтоб проверить меняется ли значение speed при нажатии цифр на клавиатуре, я вставил console.log(speed); в setDirection  и таки да меняется, но скорость не меняется. При нажатии клавиши направления, консоль возвращает speed = 5 по умолчанию. Без костыля, в виде значения по умолчанию ( = 5 // в аргументе), выдаёт undefined. Костыль вроде бы и нужен, но по ходу он и мешает, возвращая всё к значению по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ball game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas class="" id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let width = canvas.width;
    let height = canvas.height;
    let speeds = {
      96: 0,
      97: 1,
      98: 2,
      99: 3,
      100: 4,
      101: 5,
      102: 6,
      103: 7,
      104: 8,
      105: 9
    }

    let circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
      if (fillCircle) {
        ctx.fill();
      } else {
        ctx.stroke();
      };
    };

    let Ball = function () {
      this.x = width / 2;
      this.y = height / 2;
      this.speed = 0;
      this.xSpeed = 1;
      this.ySpeed = 0;
    };

    Ball.prototype.move = function () {
      this.x += this.xSpeed*this.speed;
      this.y += this.ySpeed*this.speed;

      if (this.x < 10 || this.x > width-10) {
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
      };
      if (this.y < 10 || this.y > height-10) {
        this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
      }
      // console.log('MoveX ' + this.xSpeed);
    };

    Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
      circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true);
    }

    Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
      if (direction === 'up' ) {
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = -1;
        console.log(this.speed);
      } else if (direction === 'down' ) {
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = 1;
      } else if (direction === 'left' ) {
        this.xSpeed = -1;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      } else if ( direction === 'right' ) {
        this.xSpeed = 1;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      } else if (direction === 'stop' ) {
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      }

      console.log('Direction ' + this.xSpeed)
    };

    Ball.prototype.setSpeed = function (newSpeed) {
      if (newSpeed !== undefined) {
        this.speed = newSpeed;
        console.log(this.speed)
      }
    }

    let ball = new Ball();

    let keyActions = {
      32: 'stop',
      37: 'left',
      38: 'up',
      39: 'right',
      40: 'down',
    };

    $('body').keydown(function (event) {
        let direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
        let speed = speeds[event.keyCode];
        ball.setDirection(direction);
        ball.setSpeed(speed);
    });

    setInterval(function () {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      ball.draw();
      ball.move();
      ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }, 30);
```

Comment: Нормально работает

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').keydown(function (event) {
        if( event.keyCode === 32 ||
        event.keyCode === 37 ||
        event.keyCode === 38 || 
        event.keyCode === 39 ||
        event.keyCode === 40) {
            let direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
            ball.setDirection(direction);
        } else {
            speed = speeds[event.keyCode];
        }

})
```

Comment: Та же самая проблема была.
По книжке "Javascript для детей".
Добавил условие проверки, какие клавиши жмутся, всё заработало. Шар не пропадает, скорость меняется.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]